# How to show circularprogressindicator along with bottomsheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet, progress-indicator

i am using bottomsheet in my code and due to that it is not showing my circularprogressindicator when isLoading is true but else part of ternary operator is working perfectly. Is there anyother way to do that. Or where i am doing wrong in the code?

```
  (isLoading==true) ? Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 24,
      width: 24,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: CommonColors.primaryColor,
        strokeWidth: 1,
      ),
    ),
  )
      :
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: clist.cartlist.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _buildCartProduct(index);
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Divider(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 80,
      )
    ],
  ),
  bottomSheet: isLoading?Container():Container(
    height: 80.0,
    color: CommonColors.secondaryBackgroundColor,
    child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),child:
        Text('Total: \$${clist.getSubTotal()}',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16),)),
        Expanded(
          child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){},
            color: CommonColors.primaryColor,
            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'PLACE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: CommonColors.secondaryBackgroundColor,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

in this part you're showing an empty container if loading

```
bottomSheet: isLoading?Container():Container(
```

so change it to be your CircularProgressIndicator

```
bottomSheet: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator():Container(
```

Comment: But if i do that there will be two progress indicator showing but i just want to show only one.

Answer (score 0):

> simple put it the code!

```
static void customBotFtomSheet(BuildContext context) async {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(15.0)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: BrandColors.kWhite,
      elevation: 0,
      context: context,
      // showDragHandle: true,

      isScrollControlled: true,
      isDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
 }
```